# How do you reason about the order of execution of functions in a monadT stack?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

General theme: While I find the idea of stacking monads together is very appealing, I am having a lot of trouble picturing how the code is executed, and what are the appropriate orders to run the layers. Below is one example of a stack: Writer, State, State, and Error, in no particular order ( or is there? ).

```
-----------------------
-- Utility Functions --
-----------------------

type Memory  = Map String Int
type Counter = Int
type Log     = String

tick :: (MonadState Counter m) => m ()
tick = modify (+1) 

record :: (MonadWriter Log m) => Log -> m ()
record msg = tell $ msg ++ "; "

------------------
-- MonadT Stack --
------------------

mStack :: ( MonadTrans t, MonadState Memory m, MonadState Counter (t m), MonadError ErrMsg (t m), MonadWriter Log (t m) ) => t m Int
mStack = do
    tick
    m <- lift get
    let x = fromJust ( M.lookup "x" m ) in x
    record "accessed memory"
    case True of 
        True  -> return 100
        False -> throwError "false"
```

Please note in `mStack`, whether an error is thrown or not has nothing to do with any other part of the function.

Now ideally I want the output to look like this:

```
( Right 100, 1, "accessed memory", fromList [...])
```

or in general:

```
( output of errorT, output of stateT Counter, output of writerT, output of StateT Memory )
```

But I cannot get it to work. Specifically, I tried running the stack as if Error is on the outermost layer:

```
mem1 = M.fromList [("x",10),("y",5)]
runIdentity $ runWriterT (runStateT (runStateT (runErrorT mStack ) 0 ) mem1 ) ""
```

But am getting this error message:

```
  Couldn't match type `Int' with `Map [Char] Int'
```

---

The above instance aside, in general, when I am calling:

`runMonadT_1 ( runMonadT_2 expr param2 ) param1`,

are the functions relating to `monadT_2` run first, then that output is piped into the functions relating to `monadT_1` ? So in other words, as imperative as the code looks in the above function `mStack`, is the order of execution entirely dependent upon the order in which the monadT are run ( aside from any rigidness in structure introduced by `lift` ) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have gotten a more informative type error if you had tried to type your computation using an explicit monad transformer stack:

```
mStack :: ErrorT String (StateT (Map String Int) (StateT Int Writer)) Int
```

Had you done that, `ghc` would have caught the type error earlier.  The reason is that you use the following two commands within `mStack` at the top-most level:

```
modify (+1)  -- i.e. from `tick`
...
yourMap <- lift get
```

If you were to give this an explicit stack, then you'd catch the mistake: both `modify` and `lift get` are going to target the first `StateT` layer they encounter, which happens to be the same `StateT` layer.

`modify` begins from the `ErrorT` layer and proceeds downward until it hits the outer `StateT` layer, and concludes that the outer `StateT` must be using an `Int` state.  `get` begins from the outer `StateT` layer, notices that it's already in a `StateT` layer and ignores the inner `StateT` layer entirely, so it concludes that the outer `StateT` layer must be storing a `Map`.

`ghc` then says "What gives?  This layer can't be storing both an `Int` and a `Map`!", which explains the type error you got.  However, because you used type classes instead of a concrete monad transformer stack, there was no way that `ghc` could know that this was a type error in waiting until you specified a concrete stack.

The solution is simple: just add another `lift` to your `get` and it will now target the inner `StateT` layer like you intended.

I personally prefer to avoid `mtl` classes entirely and always work with a concrete monad transformer stack using the `transformers` library alone.  It's more verbose because you have to be precise about which layer you want using `lift`, but it causes fewer headaches down the road.